Given recurrence of $N_{n,m}$, how to find its upper bound
given recurrence $N_{n,m} = N_{n-1,m} + N_{n,m-1} + N_{n-1,m-1}$ with initial condition $N_{i,0} = 1, N_{0,j} = 1$, how to prove the upper bound of $N_{n,m}$ is $N_{n,m} \leq \frac{\{2(n+m)\}^n}{n!}$
I attempted to derive some results using mathematical induction:
$N_{n,m} = N_{n-1,m} + N_{n,m-1} + N_{n-1,m-1}$
$= \frac{\{2(n+m-1)\}^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} + \frac{\{2(n+m-1)\}^n}{n!} + \frac{\{2(n+m-2)\}^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$
$\leq \frac{\{2(n+m-1)\}^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} + \frac{\{2(n+m-1)\}^n}{n!} + \frac{\{2(n+m-1)\}^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} = \frac{2^n\{(n+m-1)\}^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} + \frac{\{2(n+m-1)\}^n}{n!} $
$= \frac{2^n\{(n+m-1)\}^{n-1}}{n!}(2n+m-1) \leq \frac{2^n\{(n+m-1)\}^{n-1}}{n!}(2n+2m-2) = \frac{2^{n+1}\{(n+m-1)\}^{n}}{n!}$
However, the expression I derived($\frac{2^{n+1}\{(n+m-1)\}^{n}}{n!}$) is not less than the right-hand side of the equation($\frac{\{2(n+m)\}^n}{n!}$) when m is large.
Is there a better bounding method that could help prove this problem?

I suggest you see this article How do I ask a good question

Have a look at the Delannoy Numbers ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delannoy_number#
